# python re.compile Beautiful soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

```
desc = re.compile('<ul class="descShort bullet">(.*)</ul>', re.DOTALL)
findDesc = re.findall(desc, link_source)

for i in findDesc:
    print i


'''
<ul class="descShort bullet">

      Sleek and distinctive, these eye-catching ornaments will be the star of your holiday decor. These unique glass icicle ornaments are individually handcrafted by artisans in India.

  </ul>
'''
```

I am attemtping to extract the description between ul class tag and /ul. I am looking for the soltuion using REGEX, as well as, beautifulsoup.

Comment: I guess at least you *tried* to use an HTML parser... unfortunately though you are still using regex to parse HTML.

Comment: I am new to this site, how do I go about doing that? Thank you!

Comment: Go through the [list of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1018129/aaron-phalen?tab=questions); if there's a good answer to any of them, click the silhouette of the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, parsing HTML/XML with regexes is generally considered [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454/118520).
So, using some parser like BeautifulSoup is a better idea indeed.

What you want can be done as follows:

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<ul class="descShort bullet">text1</ul>
<a href="example.com">test</a>
<ul class="descShort bullet">one more</ul>
<ul class="other">text2</ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

# to get the contents of all <ul> tags:
for tag in soup.findAll('ul'):
    print tag.contents[0]

# to get the contents of <ul> tags w/ attribute class="descShort bullet":
for tag in soup.findAll('ul', {'class': 'descShort bullet'}):
    print tag.contents[0]
```